# Check if string contains words in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to check if a string contains a set of words in a string. using the contains keyword does not work as

I can only check for one. Please check this code:

```
let label = "write_member read_member modify_member delete_member"
if label.contains("write_member read_member modify_member") 
{
  print("true")
} 
else 
{
  print("false") 
}
```

This prints `false` every time. how can I carry out this check?

Comment: Your code prints true for me. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: No it does not. Because the contains does not return true.

Comment: [It does print true](https://replit.com/@Sweeper777/TreasuredStormyTrigger). Unless you mean you _want_ it to print false? It's very unclear what do you want to check.

Comment: A sentence (string) is not a good container for a set of words, use something like an Array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already on the right path but first you have to define what is a word. Let's use whitespace as delimiters:

```
private extension String {
    var words: Set<String> {
        return Set(components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).filter { !$0.isEmpty })
    }
}
```

Then we can use normal set operations:

```
private extension String {
    var words: Set<String> {
        return Set(components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).filter { !$0.isEmpty })
    }

    func containsWords(of string: String) -> Bool {
        return words.isSuperset(of: string.words)
    }
}

let label = "write_member read_member modify_member delete_member"
print(label.containsWords(of: "write_member read_member modify_member"))
```